# Ocultar fecha Datatime php 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo la siguiente tabla producto

```
idproducto  
numero_orden  
modelo  
tipo
fecha
fecha2
status
resultado
```

la "fecha" es la cual se registra el producto y "fecha2" es cuando se entrega el producto o se modifica, el problema es que al registrar un producto se muestra en el campo de "ultima actualizacion" 0000-00-00 00:00:00 este es mi codigo de registrar el producto

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY idproducto DESC LIMIT 1")
or die ("Error al traer los datos");

$idproducto=1000;

while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $idproducto = $extraido['idproducto'] + 1;
}


$num_orden= $_POST['num_orden'];
$modelo= $_POST['modelo'];
$tipo= $_POST['tipo'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$estatus = $_POST['status'];

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO producto(idproducto, num_orden, modelo, tipo, fecha, status) 
            VALUES ('$idproducto','$num_orden', '$modelo', '$tipo', '$fecha','$estatus')")

or die ("Error al registrar producto");
```

Con lo cual se ve de esta forma
[image]

En mi codigo para mostrar los campos es este

```
<tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['idproducto']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['num_orden']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['modelo']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['tipo']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['fecha']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['fecha2']; ?></td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php
switch ($data['status']) {
case "En espera":
    echo "En espera";

    break;


case "En proceso":
    echo "En proceso";
    break;
case "En proceso con demora":
    echo "En proceso con demora";
    break;
case "Finalizado":
    echo "Finalizado";
    break;
case "Finalizado sin reparar":
    echo "Finalizado sin reparar";
    break;
}
?>

              </td>
              <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['resultado']; 
?></td>
              <td>
```

Entonces como puedo hacer para que solo muestre el valor de fecha2 solo cuando lo allá modificado?

Comment: La columna fecha2 acepta valores nulos?

Comment: es de tipo datetime y no los acepta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Aparte del problema que tienes, y que se puede resolver como bien ha indicado @JuanPinzon, tu código se puede optimizar en varios puntos:

- Se podría evitar la mezcla de código PHP/HTML, la cual aunque válida, produce un código ilegible, difícil de depurar por confuso y horrible
- El `switch ... case` que estás usando no tiene ningún sentido.

También parece extraña la forma en que llenas el array después del `SELECT`, pero como no conozco el contexto no puedo decirte más sobre eso.

Para mejorar al menos los dos puntos mencionados anteriormente, podemos escribir el código así:

```
<?php
    /*
        Usaremos una variable llamada $html 
        para concatenar las partes de la tabla
        dado que tu código es presentado parcialmente
        conviene que crees la variable 
        donde empiezas a construir la tabla
        la idea principal es que evites mezcla PHP/HTML
    */
    $html="<table>";

    /*
        Guardamos referencias a cada dato
    */
    $idproducto=$data['idproducto'];
    $num_orden=$data['num_orden'];
    $modelo=$data['modelo'];
    $tipo=$data['tipo'];
    $fecha=$data['fecha'];
    $status=$data['status'];
    $resultado=$data['resultado'];

    /*
        Para determinar el valor de la fecha2
        usamos un ternario, para hacerla valer
        una cadena vacía cuando no haya fecha
    */

    $fecha2=($data['fecha2'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ? "" : $data['fecha2'];

    /*
        Guardamos referencia a esto que se repite una y otra vez
        Conviene señalar que es una mala práctica poner reglas
        de estilo directamente en los elementos
        La práctica recomendada es poner nombres de clases o selectores
        y aplicar el estilo por CSS
    */
    $_td='<td style="text-align:center;">';
    $td_="</td>";

    /*
        Empezamos a concatenar
        Nótese que en PHP se concatena con .=
    */
    $html.="<tr>";
        $html.="$_td$idproducto$td_";
        $html.="$_td$num_orden$td_";    
        $html.="$_td$modelo$td_";   
        $html.="$_td$tipo$td_"; 
        $html.="$_td$fecha$td_";    
        $html.="$_td$fecha2$td_";   
        $html.="$_td$status$td_";   
        $html.="$_td$resultado$td_";
    $html.="</tr>";

    /*
        Cerrar la tabla donde haya que cerrarla
    */
    $html.="</table>";

    /*
        Imprimir la tabla donde haya que imprimirla
    */
    echo $html;
?>
```

Espero sea de utilidad. El código se hizo largo por los comentarios. Si los quitas podrás apreciar mejor su simplicidad y su claridad.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu columna fecha2 no acepta null, lo que podrias hacer es comparar el texto y cambiar el valor 0000-00-00 00:00:00 por vacio, algo asi:

Antes de presentar fecha2 coloca esta condicion

```
<?php
if($data['fecha2'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
  $data['fecha2'] = "";
}
?>
```

Y luego presentas la fecha

```
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $data['fecha2']; ?></td>
```

O si quieres hacerlo mas elegante, puedes hacerlo con un operador ternario

```
<td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo ($data['fecha2'] == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?'':$data['fecha2']); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opcion seria:

1) Permitir que acepte valores nulos la fecha de modificacion, ya que no todas las inserciones que realices sufriran modificaciones posteriormente.

2) Al recuperar los datos para mostrarlos en el listado utilizar la sentencia "case" para indicar un texto cualquiera que indique que no lo haz modificado aun.

`SELECT 
      (case WHEN fecha2 is null THEN 'SIN MODIFICACION' ELSE fecha2 END) AS FECHA2

FROM 
    productos`